# "Field not found" when field is present

Tags: python, quickfix

I send a standard Market Data Incremental Refresh Request message (35 = V) and begin receiving incremental refreshes. Most of the time everything is absolutely fine and dandy. However, every once in a while, I get a strange Field not found message. For example:

> (8=FIX.4.2☺9=00221☺35=X☺49=XXX☺56=XXX☺34=4☺52=20130624-07:27:06.706☺262=XXX☺268=2☺279=2☺55=ZN☺48=00A0IN00ZNZ☺10455=ZNU3☺167=FUT☺207=CBOT☺15=USD☺200=201309☺**290=1**☺269=0☺270=126.4375☺271=9☺387=12237☺279=0☺269=0☺270=126.421875☺271=57☺10=176☺)
>
> Field not found
>
> (Message 4 Rejected: Conditionally Required Field Missing:290)
>
> (8=FIX.4.2☺9=119☺35=j☺34=3☺49=XXX☺52=20130624-07:27:07.037☺56=XXX☺45=4☺58=Conditionally Required Field Missing (290)☺372=X☺380=5☺10=144☺)

I've cut some fields containing personal information or irrelevant information. But as you can see, it is explicitly message 4 that is being rejected, because it lacks field 290, when in fact 290 is clearly there.

So, what's the deal? Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before?

I'm using the Python bindings. Fix 4.2, Python 2.7.

And for the sake of completeness, here's a message (the very next one) that didn't get rejected:

> (8=FIX.4.2☺9=00188☺35=X☺49=XXX☺56=XXX☺34=5☺52=20130624-07:27:06.706☺262=XXX☺268=1☺279=1☺55=ZB☺48=00A0IN00ZBZ☺10455=ZBU3☺167=FUT☺207=CBOT☺15=USD☺200=201309☺290=1☺269=1☺270=135.15625☺271=13☺387=5111☺10=156☺

(And no, the difference in tag 55 between the rejected and accepted messages is not the cause of this. QuickFix found 290 in plenty of 55=ZN messages.)

I know this is a pretty technical question but am hoping there is a QuickFix guru out there who might know what's going on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what's with the smilies in this code. I'd first get those out of the way..

Comment: The smiles are separators. They are meant to be there. It's not code, per se. It's a FIX message.

Comment: The smilies are fine.  Different editors convert the null-separator to weird characters sometimes; as long as the separators are visible, it's all good.

Comment: `I know this is a pretty technical question` -- Um... StackOverflow is explicitly purposed for highly technical questions. Your question would probably get downvoted/closed if it *wasn't* highly technical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message has a repeating group of two MDEntries.  Field 290 appears in the first one, but not the second one.  Your code is probably trying to extract 290 from the second one, and is thus getting the error.

Group 1 (has 290): 
`279=2☺55=ZN☺48=00A0IN00ZNZ☺10455=ZNU3☺167=FUT☺207=CBOT☺15=USD☺200=201309☺290=1☺269=0☺270=126.4375☺271=9☺387=12237☺`

Group 2 (lacks 290):
`279=0☺269=0☺270=126.421875☺271=57☺`

Examine your code that's extracting 290.  Put in an if-field-is-present check so that it doesn't try to extract a field that's not there.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is it. Bitten by repeating groups again! Thanks, Grant, for your help once more. 

I have been wanting to ask SO about how to check if a field is in a FIX message, because I don't see any way to do this in the QuickFix documentation, and in my understanding a check in python itself (like a try/except clause) would not work. It just seems to me that this check has to be called as a QuickFix method somehow. Any pointers?

Comment: [FieldMap::isSetField()](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_field_map.html) is probably what you want.  For the group, you need to call `isSetField` on the *Group* object, not the *Message* object.  How about an upvote for my trouble? :)

Comment: Excellent, I will check it out. I would upvote you lots, you deserve it, but I don't have the rep. How about upvoting me for the technicality of my questions, and eventually I can return the favor? ;) Thanks again Grant.

Comment: Now I feel like a fully-fledged member of SO. Cheers!

Comment: As a final epitaph to this question, I thought you would find it gratifying to see what printing the result of an isSetField method call gives: 
True
False
Field not found
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
Field not found
True
True
True
True

Answer (score -1):

please take a look at this page:
http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/msgType_X_88.html

in the paragraph starting with: "Adding, Changing, or Deleting Market Data Entries"

I've never worked with this kind of messages, but hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the link, stexcec. Onixs is a handy website and I go there sometimes, then I learned that they have basically copied and pasted all their content from the fixwiki!

Comment: Sorry for my poor answer. Thanks to all.